# How to use flex with my own parser?

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I want to leave the lexical analysis to lex but develop the parser on my own.

I made a token.h header which has the enums for token types and a simple class hierarchy,

For the lex rule:

```
[0-9]+ {yylval = new NumToken(std::stoi(yytext));return NUM;}
```

How do I get the NumToken pointer from the parser code?
Suppose I just want to print out the tokens..

```
while(true)
{
    auto t = yylex();
    //std::cout <<yylval.data<<std::endl; // What goes here ?
}
```

I can do this with yacc/bison, but can not find any documentation or example about how to do this manually.

Comment: Can't you just have the lexer call callback functions into your code?

So instead of just creating a NumToken call a function onNumToken() that will do the work you want done..

Comment: That seems like a good idea.
It will need some global state, but I can probably ignore that.

Comment: You can try the following suggested method `http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Cxx.html`

Of embedding the scanner in a C++ class. This will allow you to call methods on the class instance as actions and avoid global state

Answer (score 1):

In a traditional bison/flex parser, `yylval` is a global variable defined in the parser generated by bison, and declared in the header file generated by bison (which should be #include'd into the generated scanner). So a simple solution would be just to replicate that: declare `yylval` (as a global) in `token.h` and define it somewhere in your parser.

But modern programming style has shifted away from the use of globals (for good reason), and indeed even `flex` will generate scanners which do not depend on global state, if requested. To request such a scanner, specify

```
%option reentrant
```

in your scanner definition. By default, this changes the prototype of `yylex` to:

```
int yylex(yyscan_t yyscanner);
```

where `yyscan_t` is an opaque pointer. (This is C, so that means it's a `void*`.) You can read about the details in the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant.html); the most important takeaway is that you can ask flex to also generate a header file (with `%option header-file`), so that other translation units can refer to the various functions for creating, destroying and manipulating a `yyscan_t`, and that you need to minimally create one so that `yylex` has somewhere to store its state. (Ideally, you would also destroy it.) [Note 1].

The expected way to use a reentrant scanner from `bison` is to enable `%option bison-bridge` (and `%option bison-location` if your lexer generates source location information for each token). This will add an additional parameter to the `yylex` prototype:

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE *yylval_param, yyscan_t scanner);
```

With `%option bison-locations', two parameters are added:

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE *yylval_param,
          YYLTYPE *yylloc_param,
          yyscan_t scanner);
```

The semantic type `YYSTYPE` and the location type `YYLTYPE` are *not* declared by the flex-generated code. They must appear in the `token.h` header you #include into your scanner.

The intention of the bison-bridge parameters is to provide a mechanism to return the semantic value `yylval` to the caller (i.e. the parser). Since `yylval` is effectively the same as the parameter `yylval_param` [Note 2], it will be a *pointer* to the actual semantic value, so you need to write (for example) `yylval->data = ...` in your flex actions.

So that's one way to do it.

A possibly simpler alternative to `bison-bridge` is just to provide your own `yylex` prototype, which you can do with the macro `YY_DECL`. For example, you could do something like this (if YYSTYPE were something simple):

```
#define YY_DECL std::pair<int, YYSTYPE> yylex(yyscan_t yyscanner)
```

Then a rule could just return the pair:

```
[0-9]+ {return std::make_pair(NUM, new NumToken(std::stoi(yytext));}
```

Obviously, there are many variants on this theme.

---

#### Notes

1. Unfortunately, the generated header includes quite a lot of unnecessary baggage, including a bunch of macro definitions for the standard "globals" which won't work because in a reentrant scanner these variables can only be used in a flex action.
2. The scanner generated with `bison-bridge` defines `yylval` as a macro which refers to a field in the opaque state structure, and stores `yylval_param` into this field. `yyget_lval` and `yyset_lval` functions are provided in order to get or set this field from outside of `yylex`. I don't know why; it seems somewhere between unnecessary and dangerous, since the state will contain the *pointer* to the value, as supplied in the call to `yylex`, which may well be a dangling pointer once the call returns.